# query calling two other queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am writing a query in an Access 2010 database which calls two other queries in the same Access 2010 database.  The result will be a tabular report with the following fields:

```
FirstName, LastName, HomePhone, ClientNumber, Level, nextDate, Type
```

The list of customers/rows is generated by Query1, which also populates FirstName, LastName, HomePhone, and Client Number.  And then Query2 populates Level, nextDate, and Type FOR EACH customer row defined in the first query above.

So far, the summary query that I have is:

```
SELECT Query1.FirstName, Query1.LastName, Query1.HomePhone, Query1.ClientNumber, Query2.[Level], Query2.nextDate, Query2.Type 
FROM Query1 
INNER JOIN Query2 ON Query1.ClientNumber=Query2.ClientNumber;
```

But when I try to view the results of this summary query in datasheet view, Access gives me a dialog box asking for Query2.ClientNumber, which indicates that something in the code is not referencing that variable properly.

For reference, here is the code for Query1:

```
SELECT ActiveCustomers.FirstName, ActiveCustomers.LastName, tblClientAddress.HomePhone, ActiveCustomers.ClientNumber 
FROM 
(
    SELECT Clients.ClientNumber, Clients.FirstName, Clients.LastName   
    (     
        SELECT COUNT(ReferralDate)      FROM IntakeTable      WHERE Clients.ClientNumber = IntakeTable.ClientNumber AND Len(ReferralDate & '') > 0   
    ) AS IntakeCount, 
    (     
        SELECT COUNT(ExitDate)      FROM ExitTable      WHERE Clients.ClientNumber = ExitTable.ClientNumber AND Len(ExitDate & '') > 0   
    ) AS ExitCount 
FROM Clients
)  AS ActiveCustomers  
INNER JOIN tblClientAddress ON ActiveCustomers.ClientNumber=tblClientAddress.ClientNumber
WHERE IntakeCount > ExitCount  AND tblClientAddress.CurrentResidence = True;
```

And here is the code for Query2:

```
SELECT a.[Level], max(a.dte) AS nextDate, IIf([Type1Date]<[Type2Date],"t1","t2") AS [Type]
FROM (
    select [Level], Type1Date as dte
    FROM CommunicationTable WHERE ClientNumber=1  
    UNION
    select [Level], Type2Date as dte
    FROM CommunicationTable WHERE ClientNumber = 1  
)  AS a
GROUP BY a.[Level], IIf(a.[Type1Date]<a.[Type2Date],"t1","t2");
```

Can someone show me how to set this up so that it runs properly?

Answer (score 2):

When you have joined and nested queries like this, it helps to picture what is being "exposed" to the outer queries. `Query2` has a nested query, `a`, that does not expose `ClientNumber`, so `Query2` cannot (and does not try to) expose `ClientNumber` to the join. Try this for `Query2`:

```
SELECT a.[Level], max(a.dte) AS nextDate, IIf([Type1Date]<[Type2Date],"t1","t2") AS [Type], a.ClientNumber
FROM (
    select [Level], Type1Date as dte, ClientNumber
    FROM CommunicationTable WHERE ClientNumber=1  
    UNION
    select [Level], Type2Date as dte
    FROM CommunicationTable WHERE ClientNumber = 1  
)  AS a
GROUP BY a.[Level], IIf(a.[Type1Date]<a.[Type2Date],"t1","t2");
```

That way, the outside query can "see" the ClientNumber column on both sides of the join.

Comment: Thank you.  +1 for a good suggestion. But it is a little more nuanced than just that.  Query2 says WHERE ClientNumber=1.  However, the value for ClienNumber in the WHERE condition needs to change for each row in order for the join to list either populated values or null values for each row returned by Query1.  The summary query now outputs empty rows but does show the labels of all 7 fields.  Can you suggest a way to change the syntax to replace 1 with a variable from Query1 in the "WHERE ClientNumber=1" part of Query2?

Comment: @CodeMed As you noted, the WHERE clauses in the subqueries of `Query2` are only going to return values for `ClientNumber = 1`. If you want to get results for all clients (ClientNumber values) you'll need to get rid of those WHERE clauses and add ClientNumber to the GROUP BY clause. Then, `Query2` will return rows for all clients and you can use the (now visible) ClientNumber field in JOINs with other tables/queries when you reference `Query2` in other queries.

Comment: @GordThompson I want you to know that your insights are very much appreciated.  Thank you.